# Referencing PHP from an ext JavaScript file

Tags: php, javascript

I'm having some trouble trying to get my tweets on the header of my site using an ext PHP file, referenced from a JavaScript tag - I have included the header reference in the PHP file and output as last line is javascript encompassing the echo.

```
<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
//Get Latest Tweet
function latest_tweet($username,$tweetnumber){
   $url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:$username&amp;rpp=10";
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
   $tweettitle = $xml->entry[$tweetnumber]->title;
   $mytweet = $xml->entry[$tweetnumber]->content;
   $firstChar = substr($tweettitle, 0, 1);
   //Exclude @ replies
   if($firstChar == "@"){
      //If this tweet is an @ reply move on to the previous one
      while ($firstChar == "@"){
         $tweetnumber++;
         $tweettitle = $xml->entry[$tweetnumber]->title;
         $mytweet = $xml->entry[$tweetnumber]->content;
         $firstChar = substr($tweettitle, 0, 1);
         if($firstChar != "@"){
            //If the previous tweet is not an @ reply output it
            return $mytweet;
         }
      }
   } else {
      //If first tweet is not an @ reply output it
      return $mytweet;
   }
}
//End Get Latest Tweet

//output
echo "document.write(latest_tweet('mikedeveloper', 0))";
?>
```

Comment: `latest_tweet` is a PHP function, not a JavaScript function. You cannot call a PHP function from JavaScript this way. Why don't you just output the content with PHP? `echo latest_tweet('mikedeveloper', 0);`.

Comment: I wanted to keep my JavaScript and PHP separate to the mark up.

Comment: But the `document.write(...)` seems to be unnecessary... well I guess it depends on how you include this file. `document.write` will overwrite the current document if it is called after the document was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `latest_tweet` is a PHP function, you have to invoke it from PHP, but you are trying to invoke from javascript. Try this:

```
echo "document.write('" . latest_tweet('mikedeveloper', 0) . "')";
```

Comment: Ah thank you!. Only just started with PHP in the last week but you've been a great help.

Comment: Please also consider the comment added by @Felix Klink to your question. Trying to accomplish that by referencing a php on a `<script>` tag is odd... I think you should be using Ajax, or directly outputting the tweets from PHP in the middle of your HTML markup.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again!. You mean include the PHP in the html?. I just read somewhere you could accomplish this in this manner and thought like JavaScript it'd be less intrusive.

Comment: Just to let you know, having read comments and best advice, decided against this method and to leave the file as a .PHP file as recommended and naturally have it parsed as such. Then I changed the ext with an Apache directive which shows HTML on the site. Many thanks, all. I'm new to PHP so all help is appreciated.